# Failed to load xerial snappy-java when starting Elasticsearch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

I am getting an exception when I start Elasticsearch.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xerial/snappy/Snappy
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.snappy.xerial.XerialSnappy.<clinit>(XerialSnappy.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-0.20.6.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.<clinit>(CompressorFactory.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-0.20.6.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:161) [elasticsearch-0.20.6.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:109) [elasticsearch-0.20.6.jar:na]
    at no.breakpoint.service.search.SearchClientFactory.getClient(SearchClientFactory.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0]
//....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ~[na:1.7.0]
```

Dependency in POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I add this dependency in POM, the exception disappear. However, what is the reason (or, I know this usually means that the library is not found on the classpath and adding the dependency fixes it, but is it something wrong with the transitive dependencies of Elasticsearch)?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this earlier. I was able to solve it by using 1.0.5-M1 version, instead of 1.0.4.1

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate, this is a known problem with snappy 1.0.4 using java 7 on OSX, [here's the issue on github](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/6). You can fix this problem, as juanpaolo notes, with the following:

```
<snappy.version>1.0.5-M1</snappy.version>
```

then, in dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
   <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
   <version>${snappy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```